# Python 3, Whenever I try to use \r and time.sleep() in the same loop, there is no output

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a simple Countdown Timer using the time module, and I was planning on having the timer go down and just overwrite the same line in the output so the output doesn't become full of useless lines. (Basically just have one changing line) The problem is that whenever I use \r to do so and use time.sleep(1) for a second to pass, nothing shows up. It's just blank. If I get rid of the time.sleep it usually works. I'm new and was wondering for any possible solutions or advice/information. Thank you!!

```
import time
def timer(t):
    while t != 0:
        minutes, seconds = (divmod(t, 60)) 
        time_left = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(minutes, seconds)
        print(time_left, end = "\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t-= 1
t = 120
timer(t)
```

Comment: Add `flush=True` to you print to avoid line buffering.

Comment: I tried the above in a python 3 conda environment and it all seems to work fine to me. Displays 4 integer digits and a ":" on a single line in my terminal .

Comment: The results may vary depending on what version of Python you are using and what you are using for a terminal.  I tested several techniques reported in previous Stack Overflow answers using Python 3.8 and IDLE as the terminal and none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I found that putting the `\r` at the start of the string works.

```py
print("\r", time_left, end = "", flush=True)
```

The `flush=True` doesn't seem to be required, but I've left it in just in case.

Comment: Oh this works! Thank you so much for your help!! :)

Comment: Glad to help. To show that this solved your problem, please upvote and accept (click the check) the answer.

Comment: Just did! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I added clear output function in the code. To over-write the previous printed value with the new one.Code will work for python Notebook.

```
import time
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
def timer(t):
    print("In FUntion")
    while t != 0: #This keeps the loop going until t reaches nothing, basically 0.
        minutes, seconds = (divmod(t, 60)) 
        clear_output(wait=True)
        time_left = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(minutes, seconds)
        print(time_left)
        time.sleep(1)
        t-= 1
t = 120
timer(t)
```

Kindly up-vote and mark tick if helpful